# Pandas rolling aggregate list of functions. ValueError: no results

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, rolling-computation

Aggregate method after rolling doesn't work for list of functions.

This code rises an Valueerror.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(3), 'date':pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-03')})
df.rolling('6D', min_periods=1, on='date', closed='left').agg([sum])
```

BUT this code works fine for a single function.

```
df.rolling('6D', min_periods=1, on='date', closed='left').agg(sum)
```

Error text:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-389-91b03860c0e6> in <module>
----> 1 df.rolling('6D', min_periods=1, on='date', closed='left').agg([sum])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/window.py in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   1683     @Appender(_shared_docs['aggregate'])
   1684     def aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1685         return super(Rolling, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
   1686 
   1687     agg = aggregate

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/window.py in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    310 
    311     def aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
--> 312         result, how = self._aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
    313         if result is None:
    314             return self.apply(arg, raw=False, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    557             return self._aggregate_multiple_funcs(arg,
    558                                                   _level=_level,
--> 559                                                   _axis=_axis), None
    560         else:
    561             result = None

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _aggregate_multiple_funcs(self, arg, _level, _axis)
    615         # if we are empty
    616         if not len(results):
--> 617             raise ValueError("no results")
    618 
    619         try:

ValueError: no results
```

Comment: You can use a `dict` instead

Comment: I think it's just one window = one function, like in any other implementation of windowing (at least the ones, that I know of). Interestingly - trying the solution with dict - I get ```Segmentation fault``` error, and my python session is killed

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski  Documentation of `pandas.core.window.Rolling.aggregate` declares that list of functions is a legal parameter. Also list of functions works fine when I don't use period as a window. Example `df[['col1']].rolling(2).agg([sum,max])`

Comment: @lostCode Could you provide a solution. I tried `df.rolling('6D', min_periods=1, on='date', closed='left').agg({'col1':[sum, max]})` but got another exception

Comment: both must be in col1? could you create another column

Comment: @lostCode yes, I have many columns in real dataframe and I can't replicate them as RAM limits

Answer (score 0):

I find a workaround. I don't know why but we need to use date columns as index in that case.

```
df.set_index('date').rolling('6D', min_periods=1, closed='left').agg(['sum','max'])
```

result

```
           col1     
            sum  max
date                
2018-01-01  NaN  0.0
2018-01-02  0.0  1.0
2018-01-03  1.0  2.0
```